# Why useradd shows Permission denied error

Tags: permissions, users, useradd

I am working on CentOS 5.5.

When I run the `useradd` command as root, then its working.

But when I run the same command from one of the user, then it shows

```
-bash: /usr/sbin/useradd: Permission denied
```

Why all this happening?

I also added `/usr/sbin` in `PATH`.

I added user from root by following commands:

```
groupadd service
useradd -g service service
passwd service
```

I installed Operating System two three times, all the time it shows same error.

Help me please, I didn't understand why all this happening.

Comment: It would be better if you could split your question in 2. One question regarding useradd and one regarding vim.

Comment: @Huygens ohk I will do that.

Answer (score 4):

The command `useradd` needs some special privilege to modify the system settings. Hence, you get a permission denied when using it as a normal user.

To be able to call useradd from a normal user, you need to configure `sudo`. It is not too complicated, see this tutorial: http://quaid.fedorapeople.org/sudo-tutorial/ especially chapter 4.